# Preventing SwiftUI rectangles from going outside active area during drag gesture

Tags: swiftui, gesture

I'm working on a SwiftUI project where I have one rectangle that I want to be draggable within an active area. However, I'm facing an issue where the rectangle can go outside the active area during the drag gesture. I want to constrain the position of the rectangle so that it stays within the active area during the drag gesture. How can I achieve this? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var position = CGSize.zero
    @State var lastPosition = CGSize.zero
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color(red: 0.5450980392156862, green: 0.5450980392156862, blue: 0.5450980392156862))
                .aspectRatio(0.75, contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(height: 550)
                .cornerRadius(30)
                .offset(x: position.width, y: position.height)
                .animation(.spring(response: 0.4, dampingFraction: 0.4, blendDuration: 0.4))
                .gesture(
                    DragGesture()
                        .onChanged({ value in
                            position = CGSize(width: lastPosition.width + value.translation.width, height: lastPosition.height + value.translation.height)
                        })
                        .onEnded({ value in
                            lastPosition = position
                        })
                )
                .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When setting the position why don't you just add a limit to the x and y so that it stays within your bounds?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I agree that setting limits on the x and y coordinates would be a solution to keep the rectangles within bounds during dragging. However, I'm facing some difficulties in implementing these limits effectively. I've tried a few approaches, but the rectangles still tend to go outside the bounds, especially when using a complex layout with multiple rectangles. I'm looking for some guidance or code examples on how to properly constrain the position of the rectangles. Any further insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does something like this match what you are looking for?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var position = CGSize.zero
    @State private var rectangleSize = CGRect.zero
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color(red: 0.5450980392156862, green: 0.5450980392156862, blue: 0.5450980392156862))
                    .aspectRatio(0.75, contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(width: 20, height: 50)
                    .overlay(
                        GeometryReader { geo in
                            Color.clear
                                .onAppear{
                                    rectangleSize = geo.frame(in: .global)
                                }
                        })
                    .cornerRadius(30)
                    .offset(position)
                    .animation(.spring(response: 0.4, dampingFraction: 0.4, blendDuration: 0.4))
                    .gesture(
                        DragGesture()
                            .onChanged({ value in
                                let xLoc = max(min(value.location.x, geometry.size.width - 1 * rectangleSize.width),0)
                                let yLoc = max(min(value.location.y, geometry.size.height - 1 * rectangleSize.height),0)
                                
                                position = CGSize(width: xLoc, height: yLoc)
                            })
                    )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The main things that were changed are using the drag location instead of the translation and calculating the offset so that the width and heights have values greater than 0 but less than the screen width